# geth node pending transactions

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, geth-debugging

Not really sure what information you need.. I am running geth with the following command:

```
/usr/bin/geth --datadir /mnt/ethereum --fast --nousb --cache 4096 --trie-cache-gens 1024 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --ws --wsaddr 0.0.0.0 --wsorigins=*
```

I then have some software sending transactions to it. I am getting back a transactionHash, however they are never getting onto the blockchain.

I have tested the code, by pointing to Infura, and this works perfectly.

The geth node is synched, any idea of why it might not be broadcasting?

Thanks in advance.
Adam